# Getting 404 error when access local application with ip address but works fine with localhost?

Tags: java, web-applications, http-status-code-404, localhost

when i accesss my web application hosted on local  tomcat with localhost i see the expected welcome page but when i access it with ip address it does not work and give
404 error. I am not getting what is the issue  with the link with ipaddress instead of localhost?

http://localhost:8080/wiki/ works fine
http://10.232.176.9:8080/wiki/ does not work

i  have confirmed the ip address from ipconfig from command prompt. Its same.

Comment: See if that IP address is in your hosts file.

Comment: provide screenshot of what you get when you type `ipconfig` on command prompt.. I am sure you are using wrong IP...

Comment: Hi duffymo , that ip address  is not in host file. But i tried giving below entry in the file 10.232.176.9 myapplication and then acessing the app with http://myapplication:8080/wiki/  but same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like your external IP, so you might have a router/firewall blocking access.
Have you tried accessing with `127.0.0.1:8080`, or from (another computer in your) network, using an IP like `10.1.1.X`, `192.168.1.X` or whathever your subnet is?

Comment: Hi marcelo 127.0.0.1:8080 works fine too.If i am trying to acess the application from same machine on which application is hosted how will firewall/router come in to picture

Comment: tried to access the the link from other machine too, getting same error

Comment: @MSach, if you are using the external IP it doesn't matter if you are on the host machine - it will forward the request through DNS and external routers anyway (*pretty* sure, not 100%)

Comment: I assume his subnet is [10.x.x.x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network), as per his IP address (which thus is network local).

Answer (score 2):

I'm almost sure it has something to do with what IP addresses the webserver is listening too. See [this Apache documentation page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/bind.html) to see how it's done in Apache; which, I believe, Tomcat is based on...?

Comment: No, Tomcat is not based on Apache httpd

Comment: For those using Apache 2.4: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html